# Use update panel on click events

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-ajax, updatepanel

I have a `DataList` control with the headers as a clickable `LinkButtons`

```
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dl1" OnItemDataBound="dl_ItemDataBound">
   <HeaderTemplate>
    <asp:LinkButton ID="lbl1"  runat="server" Visible="false" OnClick="lbl_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
   <asp:LinkButton ID="lbl2"  runat="server"  Visible="false" OnClick="lbl_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
 </HeaderTemplate>
     <ItemTemplate>
            ............
 </ItemTemplate>
     </asp:DataList>
```

On the ItemDataBound I'm assigning text and making visible based on few conditions

Whenever the on click event is raised I'm displaying another control down this DataList control, but this makes my DataList control to refresh which I want to prevent it.

The purpose to stop refresh is that the ItemTemplate contains a Label which I'm styling it on the ItemBound, due to refresh the styles are removed and I don't want to bind for every postback so to have my styles

I have tried using `update panel` on the top of the DataList as

```
<asp:UpdatePanel runat="server" ID="UpdatePanel1" UpdateMode="Conditional">
<ContentTemplate>
<asp:DataList runat="server" ID="dl1" OnItemDataBound="dl_ItemDataBound">
..........
</ContentTemplate></asp:UpdatePanel>
```

This has stopped the click event to be raised. How to achieve this.

Comment: Try changing to asp repeater?

Comment: @User2012384 I don't want to change the controls

Comment: Then it's a bit hard, you know when you click the button, the datalist will data bind again and when it data bind, it reinitialize the dropdown

Comment: I'm sorry maybe I haven't explained my question properly or you have misinterpreted it. I don't have a dropdown, datalist is refreshing causing  styles disappear @User2012384